# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract link under tree structure

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Suppose the html web page like this:

```
<html>
    <div id="a">
        <div class="aa">
            <p>
                <a id="ff" href="#">ff</a>
                <a id="gg" href="#">gg</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bb">
            <p>
                <a id="ff" href="#">ff</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
    </div>
</html>
```

After using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.read())
```

I have the html web page, and I would like to get the the link that is under the tree structure: `<html>` -> `<div id="a">` -> `<div class="aa">`.

How can I write the following Python code using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: It would be useful if you mentioned what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Without more info about your data it is difficult to give you a concise solution that will cover all possible inputs. To help you on your way, here's a walkthrough which will hopefully lead you to a solution that suits your needs.

The following will give us `<div id="a">` (there should only be one element with a specific id):

```
top_div = soup.find('div', {'id':'a'})
```

We can then proceed to retrieve all inner divs with `class='aa'` (possible to have more than one):

```
aa_div = top_div.findAll('div', {'class':'aa'})
```

From there, we can return all links for each div found:

```
links = [div.findAll('a') for div in aa_div]
```

Note that `links` contains a nested list since `div.findAll('a')` will return a list of `a` nodes found. There are [various ways to flatten such a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python).

Here's an example which iterates through the list and prints out the individual links:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for a in chain.from_iterable(links):
...   print a
... 
<a id="ff" href="#">ff</a>
<a id="gg" href="#">gg</a>
```

---

The solution presented above is rather long winded. However, with more understanding of the input data a much more compact solution is possible. For example, if the data is exactly as you've show and there will always be that one `div` with `class='aa'` then the solution could simply be:

```
>>> soup.find('div', {'class':'aa'}).findAll('a')
[<a id="ff" href="#">ff</a>, <a id="gg" href="#">gg</a>]
```

---

#### Using CSS selectors with BeautifulSoup4

If you're using a newer version of BeatifulSoup (version 4), you could also use the [`.select()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which provides [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) support. The elaborate solution I provided at the beginning of this answer could be re-written as:

```
soup.select("div#a div.aa a")
```

For BeautifulSoup v3, you can add on this functionality using [soupselect](http://code.google.com/p/soupselect/).

However, do note the following statement from the docs (emphasis mine):

> This is a convenience for users who know the CSS selector syntax. You can do all this stuff with the Beautiful Soup API. And **if CSS selectors are all you need, you might as well use lxml directly, because it’s faster**. But this lets you combine simple CSS selectors with the Beautiful Soup API.

Comment: Why not the css-like selectors? `soup("div#a div.aa a")`

Comment: @Kos I'm under the impression that you'd need something like [soupselect](http://code.google.com/p/soupselect/). Has css-style selectors been added to BeautifulSoup? Would be awesome if it has.

Comment: Yup, at least partially. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors The syntax is `soup.select(...)`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with a quick mention of `.select()` (BS4 only I believe, introduced in [this revision](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/revision/180)).

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it this way:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://www.website.com'
file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url)
html_object = BeautifulSoup(file_pointer)

link_list = []
links = html_object('div',{'class':'aa'})[0]('a')
for href in links:
    link_list.append(href['href'])
```

This returns a list of 'links' that can be called by offset:

```
link_1 = link_list[0]
link_2 = link_list[1]
```

Alternatively, if you want the text associated with the links (ie 'Click Here' vs '/Product/Store/Whatever.html'), you could change this same code very slightly and produce the desire results:

```
link_list = []
links = html_object('div',{'class':'aa'})[0]('a')
for text in links:
    link_list.append(text.contents[0])
```

Again, this will return a list so you will have to call the offsets:

```
link_1_text = link_list[0]
link_2_text = link_list[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found this info on the official beautiful soup documentation:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
```

You can see more about beautiful soup here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Regards